# Is it possible to call sql function after case statement end

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to call sql function after case statement end but getting error.
i am getting error on the following sql query.

```
SELECT IsNULL(CONCAT(emp.FirstName,' ',emp.MiddleName,' ',emp.LastName),'-') 
    EmployeesName,
       dbo.EmployeeScheduleTime(scdle.StartTime,scdle.EndTIme),
       case dbo.GetDayName(scdle.Date)
         when 'Tuesday' then 
          dbo.EmployeeScheduleTime(scdle.StartTime,scdle.EndTIme)  
         else Null
          END dbo.GetDayNameWithDate(scdle.Date)
           FROM Employee emp Left outer join Department dpt on 
            emp.DepartmentID=dpt.DepartmentID
                  inner join Shift shft on shft.ShiftID=emp.ShiftID
                  left outer join Schedule scdle on 
                   scdle.ShiftID=shft.ShiftID
```

Comment: Are you using Oracle? If yes is it possible from your side to switch to plsql to achieve what you want?

Comment: You've mentioned MySQL and Oracle. But `dbo.whatever` is a Microsoft SQL Server thing. So .... what dbms do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stuff that comes after `WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END` is a column alias for your result set. Column aliases must be constant and cannot be the results of functions.

So you need something like this

```
   case dbo.GetDayName(scdle.Date)
     when 'Tuesday' then 
         dbo.EmployeeScheduleTime(scdle.StartTime,scdle.EndTIme)  
     else Null
     END Tuesday
```

Comment: You may want to investigate pivoting operations. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pivot Or you may want to format your output using a programming language like php, c#, java.  What you want to do is unreasonably difficult in pure SQL. And, even if you succeed it's not portable between makes and models of database server.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have forgotten a comma after your CASE END.

...END, dbo.GetDayNameWithDate(scdle.Date)

Otherwise, if you are looking to use it as an Alias name, O.Jones is correct above.